# Ubuntu Touch onscreen keyboard disappeared | Meizu MX4 Pro

Tags: ubuntu-touch, onscreen-keyboard

Yesterday I installed Libertine on my Meizu MX4 and created a container, which is currently still empty.

Unfortunately since that the onscreen keyboard of Ubuntu Touch doesnt come up any more. And I don't mean xapps, I mean never, in no apps at all. I can't use the keyboard in Dekko, or the Messages App or anywhere else. Reboots doesn't change a thing.

I found this bug report (https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubuntu-keyboard/+bug/1579589) which seems to be the same problem, just due to another trigger. Unfortunalety the pal solved the bug, by getting his phone back to factory setting, which I really would like to prevent.

If anybody could give me a hint on how to restart/reinitiate/reinstall the native onscreen keyboard on Touch it would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the guys at Freenode #ubuntu-touch I was able to get my osk back. I downgraded to the former OTA-version and then reupgraded to latest OTA. I followed this piece of advice:
http://thinkonbytes.blogspot.de/2016/06/how-to-install-older-ota-release-in.html

Unfortunately Libertine seems to have been deleted in the process.